# Do Apple and Google really care about WCAG when it comes to color contrast?

Tags: accessibility, color, color-scheme, wcag

I am struggling to incorporate a yellow on a light background.

[image: non-compliant]

The only option to be compliant seems to be to make the yellow almost brown.

[image: compliant]

I thought I'd check how the big guys do it and it turns out, they seemingly don't?

[image: non-compliant star ratings]

[image: color contrast ratios]

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot of a Google review you refer to the yellow stars. Which of course isn't a control (the stars can't be interacted with), and should be seen as a graphical object. Since you quote WCAG specifically, I'll keep my response related to their guidelines. For Google at least (I haven't tested TripAdvisor), they seem to somewhat adhere to the following relevant guidelines:

- Arguably fails: [Non-text contrast](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#non-text-contrast)
- Passes: [Using a graphical symbol alone to convey information](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F26.html)

### First guideline

If I understand correctly, this states that it *would* require a 3:1 contrast, except if the element is not 'required to understand the content'. While it is a supporting visual representation to the numeric rating (4.2), the stars need to be interpreted correctly for a user to understand the rating scale (N out of 5). This of course is fairly critical, and then again maybe the universality of Google ratings ought to be taken into account. I can't call it unequivocally.

### Second guideline

The second guideline requires that unless 'there are other means to determine the information conveyed by the non-text marks', the criterion must fail. But again, there is the textual content. So to evaluate the stars graphic alone, Google's interface passes this guideline.

### The actual control

With a fill color of #80868B, the actual control used to enter a rating passes the 3:1 criterion. [image: Google rating form passes AA]

From what I've seen, they seem largely compliant. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ro. The other screenshot is from Apple (Maps) rather than TripAdvisor by the way.

I'd agree that as long as the textual content is shown, it would pass. That's not the case, however, for the actual reviews in Google Maps? In addition, the green (text) seem to fail requirements, too?